# Stopping overvoltage with Solar on Lithium ion tool batteries for an audio application

Tags: audio, analog, lithium-ion, over-voltage-protection

I am using two Lithium ion tool batteries (18V) to get a 36 V line. When fully charged it is greater then 40V. As they are tool batteries, undervoltage protection is already built in.

I want to be able to charge these batteries with a very high voltage solar panel (>50V). I am not interested in efficiency. I am only worried about overvoltage protection for the batteries.

Is there a cheap way to have charge protection with this system. The application is audio, so violent audio band waveforms (< 24 kHz) is not acceptable on the power lines.

Comment: Lion want to be charged with a constant current, then topped off with constant voltage. Solar power varies a lot.  I'd look into a solar charge controller.

Comment: How much current are we talking?

Comment: You'll need overvoltage protection for each battery.

Comment: Not just each battery, but each cell in the battery.   This is not a simple project *at all* and the difference between your starting point today and what you would need to even think about doing it safely is far, far beyond the scope of a question and answer here.  Probably a modern solution will involve switching conversion and sufficient filtering.  If you are adamant about avoiding that you may need to look at a lead acid battery bank and some fairly wasteful linear charging solutions...

Comment: 18/3.6V = 5S cells so you propose 10S = 36V nominal 42V max. Ideally use an off the shelf solution for charging - either a commercial product or a charge IC.|| The batteries will usually have had cell balancing - either withing the battery pack or the charger. I have seen LiIon batteries (Dyson vacuum!) with NO specific balancing and they failed after a while entirely as you'd expect. || I'd recommend 4.0V full charge per cell. Longer cycle life and slightly more forgiving of unbalanced charging. ...

Comment: ... You can make per cell dissipative top balancers with a TL431 and a few resistors per cell or add a transistor for as much balance load as you wish. You can buy Chinese N cell balance boards at OK prices and that is liable to be the easiest and probably cheapest path.

Answer (score 1):

18/3.6V = 5S cells so you propose 10S = 36V nominal 42V max.

Ideally use an off the shelf solution for charging - either a commercial product or a charger IC.

The batteries will usually have had cell balancing - either within the battery pack or the charger. I have seen (now own) LiIon batteries (Dyson vacuum!) with NO specific balancing and they failed after a while entirely as you'd expect.

I'd recommend 4.0V full charge per cell. Longer cycle life and slightly more forgiving of unbalanced charging. Somewhat per cycle 
 reduction in capacit. | You can make per cell dissipative top balancers with a TL431 and a few resistors per cell or add a transistor for as much balance load as you wish.

You can buy Chinese N cell balance boards at OK prices and that is liable to be the easiest and probably cheapest path.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thanks for the information. The Charge line and discharge lines are different, which makes me wonder what is this difference ? I think I will have to open it up and look.